Is it possible to kill a character while in their POV?
I'm writing a fantasy book that has 4 main characters. While I was planning, I thought it would be interesting to kill off one of the characters. I was thinking about doing it whilst in said character's POV; but I'm curious to know if that is even possible or if I should just have another one of the characters witness their death

Yes. I would suggest reading Tobias Wolff’s “Bullet in the Brain” for a classic example of this where the character whose mind we’re experiencing through a close third-person reading dies.

I'd also add that in Hugh Howie's Sand there's a very detailed scene (written in third person limited) of the internal experience of a character dying in a rather unusual way.
